# Создать автоинкремент поле в существующей таблице postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Необходимо в существующей таблице postgreSQL создать новую колонку с автоинкрементом,
с этим проблем не возникло, но в данной таблице уже существуют записи и у них значение в новой колонке null, а нужно чтобы они тоже заполнились, можно было бы конечно вручную, но записей несколько тысяч

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD column autoinc int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно